# bash/awk code to convert csv table format

Tags: bash, awk

I'm new in bash/awk. could you help me how could I solve this problem ? I want to write a small script for copying the miRNAs name on the left of each sequence until a new one is found. file is in CSV format. Thanks

input file:

```
Organism: hsa,
,let-7a-2-3p
,,CTGTACAGCCTCCTAGCTTTCC,
,,Totals: ,
,mir-7a-3p
,,CTATACAATCTACTGTC,
,,CTATACAATCTACTGTCT,
```

want convert like this:

```
Organism: hsa,let-7a-2-3p,CTGTACAGCCTCCTAGCTTTCC
Organism: hsa,let-7a-2-3p,Totals: 
Organism: hsa,mir-7a-3p,CTATACAATCTACTGTC
Organism: hsa,mir-7a-3p,CTATACAATCTACTGTCT
```

any help?

awk / bash code to convert

Comment: Hi Sam, I think the difficulty in here lies in the fact that most people out there (including me) have no familiarity with genetics and don't know what would be a formal definition of an miRNAs name (i.e. a specific regular expression that matches exclusively a name. For the nucleobases it seems easier ([CTAG]{4,} open end, I don't exactly the minimum amount, just an example). Furthermore, the structure of this file is not clear from this snippet. If you see the value in writing the script, I recommend spending some more time in defining the problem, then I could definitely help!

Comment: Your input file doesn't make any sense. Is that really what it looks like? If so, it's a mess.

Comment: This forum exists to help people with their code, not as a free code writing service, so please [edit] your question to show your code attempts to solve your problem so we can help you with that.

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
     {
       if($1!=""){org=$1; next}
       if(NF==2) {foo=$2; next}
       if(NF==4) {print org, foo, $3}
     }' file
```

This awk code processes a file line by line. At the beginning of the file, it sets the field separator (FS) and the output field separator (OFS) to be a comma.

For each line, it checks if the first field is not empty. If it is not, it assigns the value of the first field to the variable "org" and skips to the next line. If the number of fields (NF) is 2, it assigns the second field to the variable "foo" and skips to the next line. Finally, if the number of fields is 4, it prints the value of "org", "foo", and the third field, separated by commas.

Output:

```
Organism: hsa,let-7a-2-3p,CTGTACAGCCTCCTAGCTTTCC
Organism: hsa,let-7a-2-3p,Totals: 
Organism: hsa,mir-7a-3p,CTATACAATCTACTGTC
Organism: hsa,mir-7a-3p,CTATACAATCTACTGTCT
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly rephrasing the OP ask to:

- Find the first non-empty field in each line
- Fill the empty columns till that field with value of previous line

While possible to do in bash, awk has easier syntax for those tasks, and is much faster.

Solution using `#!` to execute awk, replace with `awk -f filename` if you prefer.

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    OFS = FS = ","   # comma delimited input/output
    np = 0           # Number of elements in previous line
}
{
    for (i=1 ; i <= NF ; i++ ) {
        # Check if first non-empty - break loop
        if ( $i != "" || i > np ) break
        # Copy values from previous line
        $i = p[i]
    }
    print
    # Update p/np with current data, for next record processing
    for (j=i ; j<=NF ; j++) p[j] = $j
    np = NF
}
```

Notes:

- p[i] stored the value of field #i in the previous record
- pn store the current number of items in p.
- Tested under Ubunto/Windows. Should work on Linux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Easy enough in raw `bash` -

```
while IFS=, read org rna dat _
do [[ -n "$org" ]] && organism="$org" && continue
   [[ -n "$rna" ]] && miRNA="$rna"    && continue
   printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "$organism" "$miRNA" "$dat"
done < file.in
```

or even

```
while IFS=, read org rna dat _; do
  case "$org,$rna,$dat" in
  ?*,,) organism="$org"                                 ;;
  ,?*,) miRNA="$rna"                                    ;;
  ,,?*) printf "%s,%s,%s\n" "$organism" "$miRNA" "$dat" ;;
  esac
done < file.in
```

Output from either -

```
Organism: hsa,let-7a-2-3p,CTGTACAGCCTCCTAGCTTTCC
Organism: hsa,let-7a-2-3p,Totals:
Organism: hsa,mir-7a-3p,CTATACAATCTACTGTC
Organism: hsa,mir-7a-3p,CTATACAATCTACTGTCT
Organism: foo,abc-1x-8-8r,lalaladeda
Organism: foo,abc-1x-8-8r,Totals: (should something go here?)
Organism: foo,and-2a-3p,DADADADADADADADAD
Organism: foo,and-2a-3p,CTATACAATCTACTGTCT
```

Still, `awk` will likely be a lot faster and more efficient, especially on files of any size.